# *ngFor Two-Way Data Binding - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, two-way-binding

I have a `BoardComponent` with several nested `BoardColumnComponent`:

```
<app-board-column class="col-sm-12 col-md-3" *ngFor="let column of board.middleColumns ; index as i" [(boardColumn)]="board.middleColumns[i]" (onRemoveClick)="removeColumn(column)"></app-board-column>
```

and the `BoardColumnComponent` with the following fields:

```
private _boardColumn: IBoardColumn;
@Output() boardColumnChange: EventEmitter<IBoardColumn> = new EventEmitter<IBoardColumn>();


@Input() 
set boardColumn(column: IBoardColumn){
    this._boardColumn = Object.assign(this.defaultColumn, column);
    this.boardColumnChange.emit(this._boardColumn);
}

get boardColumn() : IBoardColumn {
    return this._boardColumn;
}
```

So I'm facing 2 issues,

1. I need to intercept the `setter` of the boardColumn model to merge it with `defaultBoardColumn`.
2. With my current approach my app hangs, I suppose because of a recursive emit.

**Additional Data**

I've also tried the usual approach but the board doesn't change

```
@Output()
boardColumnChange = new EventEmitter<IBoardColumn>();
@Input()
boardColumn: IBoardColumn
```

If there is a different approach to fulfill this or something I'm missing, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Does it need to check if `column: IBoardColumn` is changed or can be the same value to?

Comment: what exactly is the difference between `board.middleColumns[i]` and `column`?

Comment: @methgaard using `column` there is no reference to the object so I had to use `board.middleColumns[i]` for the 2-way binding to "work".

Comment: @Swoox what I need is to merge the received object with the `defaultColumn` to avoid undefined fields and arrays.

Comment: @J.Pichardo I meant you can maybe use **ngOnChanges** but then `column: IBoardColumn` need to be different from previous value.

Comment: @Swoox sorry, but I don't quite get the _need to be different from previous value_ but the **ngOnChanges** might be the solution